# Ubuntu Server 16.04.5 - Unable to connect remotely on SSH

Tags: networking, server, ssh, remote, remote-access

*Update*

- So I tested another computer and I can externally connected to SSH. So it appears I have an issue with routing in the Ubuntu server network configuration. Can anybody help me identify what might cause Ubuntu server to only accept connections from a private IP and not an external one? - The firewall has been verified disabled so I think it must be a routing issue.

I am trying to setup SSH so I can remotely administer my home network. I am able to connect while connected to the LAN including specifying my external IP address. I have port forwarding enabled on my router and have verified on my server that port forwarding is working with TCP dump:

```
sudo tcpdump -i enp2s0f0 port 22 -n -Q inout 

    23:52:13.322036 IP [REDACTED].7754 > 192.168.1.230.22: Flags [S], seq 2665018728, win 65535, options [mss 1388,sackOK,TS val 361680193 ecr 0,nop,wscale 9], length 0
23:52:14.242965 IP [REDACTED].7754 > 192.168.1.230.22: Flags [S], seq 2665018728, win 65535, options [mss 1388,sackOK,TS val 361681194 ecr 0,nop,wscale 9], length 0
23:52:16.240930 IP [REDACTED].7754 > 192.168.1.230.22: Flags [S], seq 2665018728, win 65535, options [mss 1388,sackOK,TS val 361683210 ecr 0,nop,wscale 9], length 0
```

When I run the same command while connected to the LAN I see the server respond and am able to connect.

Here is a copy of my sshd_config:

```
 # Package generated configuration file
# See the sshd_config(5) manpage for details

# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port 22
# Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
#ListenAddress ::
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
Protocol 2
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
#Privilege Separation is turned on for security
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 1024

# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
StrictModes yes

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
#AuthorizedKeysFile     %h/.ssh/authorized_keys

# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
IgnoreRhosts yes
# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh_known_hosts
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
HostbasedAuthentication no
# Uncomment if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for RhostsRSAAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes

# To enable empty passwords, change to yes (NOT RECOMMENDED)
PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
#PasswordAuthentication yes

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no

#MaxStartups 10:30:60
#Banner /etc/issue.net

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes
```

I have also ensure firewall has been disabled:

```
sudo ufw disable
Firewall stopped and disabled on system startup
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, first time I haven't been able to find a solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Firstly I would check your system has been upgraded; as 16.04.5 implies to me you're system is well behind on upgraded packages (more than a year behind as it should report 16.04.6 - http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/03/01/ubuntu-16-04-6-lts-released/)  It may not be your issue, but maybe apply updates.

Comment: If it works on the LAN, then both client and server work properly. So it does not seem like an Ubuntu-related problem, but a (non-platform-specific) basic networking problem. Go back to your router: Really scrub your port forwarding and your router's firewall. Some ISPs block port 22, so try forwarding (and connecting via) a different port.

Comment: If I can see inbound ssh traffic using tcpdump on the server from my remote client wouldn't that eliminate the router?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1260028/edit) to clearly explain which method you are using to enable using the external IP address on the LAN.

Comment: @dsmits unrelated.... you have port forwarding configured and you have your public and private IPs listed here... not to mention (but you did!) your firewall is disabled... you really should redact some of this information....

Comment: @WU-TANG the public IP is of the client on a separate network, not the server. The firewall on the router is still enabled.

Comment: @user535733 the router is port forwarding the external IP to the server as can be seen from the tcpdump output. My understanding is that openssh by default has an option to restrict traffic locally but that option is commented out as can be seen in the sshd config.

Comment: @dsmits  What you just wrote to user535733 is exactly what I was referring to. And the firewall on the router may be irrelevant if you are telling the world that you have poked a hole in it by port forwarding and telling the exact port that is open. I am not providing assistance. I am just warning you that you have put too much sensitive information on the internet and you are making it a lot easier to be attacked... some would say inviting attacks. At least you left off your username. You may want to hide at least your router's IPs in your post... just sayin.

Comment: @WU-TANG it wasn't the external IP of my router, tcpdump was showing the external IP of the client which although sensitive, that device is firewalled and external IPs are scanned daily with BOTS so revealing that information is not really anything that cannot be found with a public scanner. I went ahead and redacted the IP anyways.

Comment: @guiverc I went ahead and updated to 16.04.6, but that didn't fix my issue. But at least I'm more secure ;-)

Comment: @dsmits Edit for the command mentioned above: creating the directory `mkdir /run/sshd` with root ownership, allows you to use port 22 and no changes to port forwarding rules. This way you can debug ssh interaction live... You would `systemctl stop sshd` and then  `/usr/sbin/sshd -D -d`. You can compare the outputs from the working client and the failing client attempts. The daemon is temporary so it dies when you close the ssh connection so you have to run it when you want it listening. Then when you're done testing restart your permanent service `systemctl restart sshd`

Comment: or in /etc/ssh_config changing the LogLevel from INFO to DEBUG3. `systemctl restart sshd` and then `tail -f /var/log/auth.log`.... duh...didn't work for me the first time so I went around my elbow.... but I will leave the other commands posted in case someone can make use of the reference. I would also check your tcpdump output with less filtering rules to see if there is other related packets going out, maybe ICMP, that are failing and telling ssh not to even bother responding. Another consideration is NAT may be getting in the way.